# How To Insert Relationship Object Data Into DB With SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask

I am using SQLAlchemy 0.9 with Python 2.7.6 and Flask.

I receive form data, place it into object and add the objects to the session. When I try to do a db.commit() I get a rollback which seems to due to the relationship object in the INSERT statement.  The SQL error is as follows:

`INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO site (name, address1, address2, postcode, city, fk_country_id, fk_school_id) VALUES (%(name)s, %(address1)s, %(address2)s, %(postcode)s, %(city)s, %(fk_country_id)s, %(fk_school_id)s) RETURNING site.id`

`INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'city': u'New York', 'fk_school_id': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x8c274ac>, 'name': u'Site1', 'address1': u'2 York Way', 'address2': u'', 'postcode': u'12345', 'fk_country_id': u'2'}`

`INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK (ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'InstrumentedAttribute'`

The relationship code in the model is as follows:

`class Site(db.Model):`
`id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)`
`school = db.relationship('School', backref = 'site', uselist = False)`

What is it about the relationship object that causes the rollback?  I am new to SQLAlchemy and so have followed what it says in the documentation regarding relationships.

Both of the data types in the models (Site, School) are ints.

Answer (score 1):

One of your fields is an object, not an ID integer or string. See:

```
'fk_school_id': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x8c274ac>
```

Whats the code at the point you define the object and db.session.add(site)? And in your School class you have a site_id field as a ForeignKey? If so when you define the School you could just say

```
school = School(name='x', .. site_id = site.id)
```

Or you could say

```
site.school = school
```

Comment: `site.fk_school_id = school.id`

Comment: sorry - network disruption.  What I meant to say what - `site.fk_school_id = school.id` is the code to assign the relationship to the object, but this is obviously incorrect.  I do not have site_id as a ForeignKey in my School class, just an id and a name.  If I don't assign something than None gets assigned, so what is the syntax I need to use to assign that as-yet-uncreated school Primary Key to my Site's ForeignKey field?

Comment: So Site class has a field 'fk_school_id field? It isn't shown in your model above.

Answer (score 1):

You need a column and a relationship. Column is missing. Something like this.

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
school_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('school.id'))

school = db.relationship(School, backref='site', uselist = False)
```

This [Documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html) should provide you with the details.